# how add the OMNeT++ bin directory to the path so that opp_configfilepath can be found?

Tags: omnet++

i'm trying to build a project in omnet++/MiXiM and compiler throws 2 erros :

**does not exist ConfigFile -- add the OMNeT++ bin directory to the path so that opp_configfilepath can be found**, or set the OMNETPP_CONFIGFILE variable to point to Makefile.inc) twice

how can add it to path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you will need to modify the `.bashrc` file in your home directory

1. acess `.bashrc`: `gedit ~/.bashrc`
2. insert this line to that file: `export PATH=$PATH:/<path-where-omnet-is-located-goes-here>/omnetpp-4.6/bin`
3. logout and login again